# Is there a limit to DocumentApp's appendParagraph function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a file that consists of many smaller files by appending each one as a new paragraph to the parent file...

But Google spits out "Document is inaccessible" after the script ends, with no errors thrown.

Anyone know?

Comment: Maybe one of the files you're trying to append as a paragraph is inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks, Cooper...but sadly, no. I did discover that some files are stuck (cannot be changed, had to copy contents to new file), but I'm still unable to append more than about 70 paragraphs.

We're in EAP too, so it's really strange. I can't find anything to indicate that I'm violating any limits. Do you happen to know if the EAP limit adjustments are added automatically upon approval?

Comment: I found these limits. Documents: Up to 1.02 million characters. If you convert a text document to Google Docs format, it can be up to 50 MB

Comment: Cooper, sorry for the delay in responding.

Where did you find this limit?

Comment: "google docs limits" Google search

Answer (score 0):

There's no documented limit of [appendParagraph(paragraph)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendparagraphparagraph) from the docs. It only says,

> "Use this version of appendParagraph when appending a copy of an
>   existing Paragraph.".